# port select --list gcc returns none(active)

Tags: gcc

I am running Yosemite and get xcode 6.1 installed on it. I also installed manually gcc with brew install gcc command.

However when i run port select --list gcc command, it returns the following message

```
 Available versions for gcc:
       none (active)
```

the gcc version shows clang with LLVM.
    gcc --version
    Configured with: --prefix=/Volumes/DEV/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --     with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
    Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
    Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
    Thread model: posix

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you resolve it the meantime and point me to the solution, or is it still in question?